# should a function return the pointer of a newly created object, or a unique_ptr of that object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I remember watching Herb Sutter on conference talks, some years ago, trying to make a guideline along these lines:

> if a function creates a new object on the heap, then it should always return it as a unique_ptr.

The idea was that it was safer, and intention-revealing.

To my surprise, this guideline seems to be missing from the CPP core guidelines today.

- Has there been an issue with this guideline? Has it been abandoned?
- Should we write functions like:

```
MyObject *create(Params p) {
  return new MyObject(p);
}
```

or

```
unique_ptr<MyObject> create(Params p) {
  return make_unique<MyObject>(p);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any general reason to prefer a raw pointer over a smart one.

Comment: Which guideline? What is their rationale? What is _your_ opinion on that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt their rationale was that the signature reveals that the caller of such a function will also own the object. In contrast, if a function returns just a pointer, you can't know whether you should just use it, or have to delete it afterwards.

In my opinion, it was a brilliant idea, and I was surprised that the rule was not to be found together with other rules about unique_ptr()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is covered in the C++ Core guidelines under I11:

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#i11-never-transfer-ownership-by-a-raw-pointer-t-or-reference-t

What you should be doing is:

```
MyObject create(Params p) {
  return MyObject(p);
}
```

Only when you absolutely need reference mechanics, i.e. when constructing a polymorphic object and returning a base class, should you do this:

```
unique_ptr<MyObject> create(Params p) {
  return make_unique<MyObject>(p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect to find it in a different chapter to the rest of the smart pointers, such as:  (F.26: Use a unique_ptr<T> to transfer ownership where a pointer is needed)

Comment: It's mentioned a few times. I just stopped at the first result my browser found that sounded applicable. Keep searching for "ownership" to find some more.

Answer (score 4):

> To my surprise, this guideline seems to be missing from the CPP core guidelines today.

This guideline *is* provided by the C++ Core Guidelines. This guideline is related to factory functions, which are functions whose primary purpose is to construct and initialize a new object.

See [C.50: Use a factory function if you need “virtual behavior” during initialization](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-factory) which states :

> **Note** The return type of the factory should normally be `unique_ptr` by default [...]